# Use sudo tee with heredoc to append to existing file

Tags: bash, files, tee, here-document

From [Generate script in bash and save it to location requiring sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414785/463994) we have this method, which I like:

```
sudo tee "$OUTFILE" > /dev/null <<'EOF'
foo
bar
EOF
```

However, I would like to use that approach to append to an existing file $OUTFILE. The above method overwrites existing file $OUTFILE.

Comment: always worth reading the manual. `man tee`

Comment: @couling-comments like this fail to consider a couple things. First, when I asked the question I was grappling with heredocs, redirection, sudo & tee. For all I knew, the issue could have been related to my usage of heredocs or something else. Second, I was not even sure the tee approach was the right one. Granted, I could have read all the manuals for every element of my proposed solution and all my alternatives. But if everyone did that, we wouldn't need a place like this to ask questions. Finally, I don't think your comment respects Stack Exchange etiquette (although I am not entirely sure)

Comment: firstly this was intended as a polite pointer to which manual was appropriate not a blind "RTFM".  That's well within stack exchange etiquette. Secondly it is also good etiquette to explain how to find an answer as well as simply give one.  To that end: if a file is being overwritten and that file is only referenced as an argument to a command, I'd start with the manual for that command not read every possible manual for your code. `man sudo` would fairly quickly point you to the fact that tee is a command in it's own right, thus lead you to `man tee`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want the `-a` option to `tee` which appends rather than overwriting.

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer to use `cat`, then go this route, first passing `$OUTFILE` as your output's receptacle:

```
$ OUTFILE=/path/to/restricted_write_access/file
$ sudo out=$OUTFILE sh -c 'cat << EOF >> $out
foo
bar
EOF'
```

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. I missed the fact that you were using `sudo sh -c`.  However, you would need to import `$OUTFILE` into the `sh -c` shell: `sudo sh -c 'cat <<EOF >>"$1" ...' sh "$OUTFILE"`

Comment: @Kusalananda. Tx. I had missed that. I only add this very late response for the sake of completion. I realized after the fact that various similar solution are posted, some of them on SE.

Answer (score 1):

tee requires you to open up a stream to /dev/null, you can get away doing this with a simple `cat`

```
cat <<EOF >> $OUTFILE
foo
bar
EOF
```

Save your keyboard!

Comment: Except that this doesn't work with `sudo` (the redirection is performed before elevating permissions, which will fail if your regular user doesn't have permissions to modify `$OUTFILE`).  That's why people use `tee` for this purpose instead.